# Groovy sql.rows returns org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No hstore extension installed

Tags: postgresql, grails, groovy

I am using Groovy Sql in Grails with named parameters to get results from a Postgres DB. My statement is generated dynamically, i.e. concatenated to become the final statement, with the params being added to a map as I go along.

```
sqlWhere += " AND bar = :namedParam1"
paramsMap.namedParam1 = "blah"
```

For readability, I am using the groovy string syntax which allows me to write my sql statement over multiple lines, like this:

```
sql = """
      SELECT *
      FROM foo
      WHERE 1=1
      ${sqlWhere}
      """
```

The expression is evaluated as a string containing the linebreaks as \n:

```
SELECT *\n ...
```

This is not a problem when I pass params like this

```
results = sql.rows(sqlString, paramsMap)
```

but it does become one if paramsMap is empty (which happens since `AND bar = :namedParam1` is not always concatenated into the query). I then get an error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No hstore extension installed
```

which does not really seem to relate to the true nature of the problem. I have for now fixed this with an if...else

```
if (sqlQuery.params.size() > 0) {
    results = sql.rows(sqlString, paramsMap)
} else {
    results = sql.rows(sqlString.replace('\n',' '))
}
```

But this seems a bit weird (especially since it does not work if I use the replace in the if-branch as well).

My question is: why do I really get this error message and is there a better way to prevent it from occuring?

Comment: my guess is, that your `sqlString` is `sql`?  or do you have have some `def sqlString = sql.toString()` around?  if you pass a `GString` to groovy sql, it will quote the `${...}` for you and you end up with bogus SQL.

Comment: Check if running the sql helps - `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`

Comment: Hi @cfrick, I have def String sqlString as a declaration but it becomes a GString along the way. I have now added a `toString()` before passing it to the `sql.rows` but the error remains

Comment: Hi @Rao, as I am not using anything hstore could offer, I would like to refrain from this, though I might try it if nothing else explains my problem, just to possibly get a better error message

Comment: log the effective statement sent to the db (might be already logged due to the error) and see what's ending up at the db. chances are high, that something does some bogus quoting.  seeing the resulting SQL usually makes it quite obvious.

Comment: @cfrick: thanks, might be a good idea, though I will have to check if we have that enabled (and enable it if not). WIll take some time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly a bug in groovy.sql.SQL implementation. The method `rows()` can't deal with an empty **map** passed as `params`. As a workaround, you can test for it and pass an empty **list** instead.

```
def paramsMap = [:]
...
if (paramsMap.isEmpty())
    paramsMap= []
```

Issue created at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8082

Comment: GROOVY-8082 is now resolved. The next release, 2.4.9, is expected in a week or two. You can now specify an empty map for the case where no placeholders values need to be replaced.